# 'The conversion of the nvarchar value '267915267915' overflowed an int column.'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've searched far and wide for a solution to this problem(including here on StackOverflow), and I do not seem to find one with the same scenario. The error I am getting is:

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '267915267915' overflowed an int column.

The problem is that I do not see where I am converting to an int column at all. Here is my C# code:

```
SqlCommand mothershipCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [Order] 
                                               WHERE [OrderNumber] = @OrderNumber", mothershipConnection);
mothershipCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", line.SONumber);
string orderID = mothershipCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Some background info:

- ID is an int column, but SELECT MAX([ID]) says that 80406 is the highest in the table.
- OrderNumber is an nvarchar(450) column.
- line.SONumber is 319279.

The last line that begins with string orderID originally was an int, but after getting this error I changed it to a long, and that didn't help, so finally I tried changing it to a string to make sure the error wasn't on my end.

I do not see where the overflow is happening, and I have no clue where the 2679... number in the error message is coming from. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue` (it's [evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)). It's inferring that `@OrderNumber` is an integer when it should be a string.

Comment: Attaching SQL Profiler to the database and watching the query as it's sent on the wire will probably show that both of the previous comments are correct.

Comment: If `OrderNumber` Is a number, wouldn't it make more sense to use a numerical data type and not a 900 byte string, that you can't index easily?

Answer (score 2):

The code contains:

```
AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", line.SONumber)
```

Because you don't specify data type for @OrderNumber parameter, it will use type from line.SONumber which I assume is integer.
So your query will be executed as

```
WHERE CAST(line.SONumber AS integer) = 319279
```

Simplest solution will be to use:

```
.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=line.SONumber.ToString();
```

Comment: CAST(line.SONumber AS bigint) solved the issue for what I needed..